# How to display specific element from each loop Jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
  var cat_str = '';
  $.each(categories, function(id, label) {
      cat_str += '<div data-cat=' + id + '>' + label + '</div>';
  });
```

Categories is a an object, and it has many elements but i want to dislay specific Label not
All elements got by loop...How can i do it ?

Comment: not all elements got by loop? what do you mean by that?

Comment: cat_str += '<div data-cat=' + id + '>' + label + '</div>';
the each loop get all Ids and labels from categories, and display, But i want to get all ids,and labels and display all ids But only one label....How to do it ?

Comment: do you know the `key` of the element to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
var label_to_show = 1; //show second label
$.each(categories, function (id, label) {
     if( label_to_show == id ){ //here id is index i.e 0, 1, 2, etc of your elements
        cat_str += '<div data-cat=' + id + '>' + label + '</div>';
        return false; //if you dont want to loop further
     }
});
```

Comment: cat_str += '<div data-cat=' + id + '>' + label + '</div>';
i want to specify the label given in the above code, for example i get 5 labels but want to dislay only first label ...

Comment: @nizamuddin see my updated code, do you mean something like that..?

Answer (score 0):

If `categories` is an object and you want to display element with key `my-key` then

```
var cat_str = '<div data-cat="my-key">' + categories['my-key']+ '</div>';
```